# How will this be solved via the use of complex numbers (angle bisector)?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

In the quadrilateral ABCD, side AD is equal to side BC, and lines AD and BC intersect at point E. Points M and N are the midpoints of sides AB and CD, respectively. Prove that the segment MN is parallel to the bisector of $\angle{AEB}$

This has a very "easy" synthetic solution which involves constructing the midpoint of lets say diagonal AC and doing further reasoning which will not be included in this post.

I personally don't like this solution as it is very hard to find without previously encountering such problems and not quite intuitive.

I have tried using polar coordinates to encode the angle bisector condition but I am not sure how to do so for the equal segments and further finish the problem.

I will be very grateful if someone provides me a hint or even a solution :D (any analytic approach would do I just figured out complex was the most suitable)

Comment: Helixglich, are you allowed to use analytic geometry ?

Comment: @Angelo isn't that obvious from the post. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. Yes I am indeed allowed to use analytic geo.

Comment: Helixglich, if you are allowed to use analytic geometry, why did you ask how your problem could be solved via complex numbers ?

Comment: @Angelo I just think that complex numbers are best here. Should I edit the question?

Comment: Bruh I found the solution. It was polar coordinates all along. Just WLOG AD = BC =1 and it is easy from there. Use complex to finish.

I will write the solution when I have time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a "natural" solution using analytic geometry.

Take $E$ as the origin, and the line bissector of angle $E$ as the $x$-axis of coordinates (and, of course the second axis directly orthogonal to the first one in $E$).

[image]

Lines $EDA$ and $ECB$ have equations $y=+ax, \ y=-ax$ resp. for a certain constant $a$.

Let $A(x_A,y_A=ax_A)$, etc...

Remark : we can assume WLOG that :

$$x_A>x_D>0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ x_B>x_C>0 \tag{0}$$

Our parallelism issue boils down to check that $M$ and $N$ have the same ordinates.

As $$\vec{AD}\binom{x_D-x_A}{a(x_D-x_A)}, \ \vec{BC}\binom{x_C-x_B}{-a(x_C-x_B)}$$

Constraint $length(AD)^2=length(BC)^2$ gives :

$$(1+a^2)(x_D-x_A)^2=(1+a^2)(x_C-x_D)^2 \ \iff \ x_A-x_D=x_B-x_C\tag{1}$$

(as a consequence of Remark (0) above).

Please note that (1) is equivalent to :

$$x_A-x_B=x_D-x_C\tag{2}$$

We can now compute :

$$\begin{cases}y_M=\tfrac12(y_A+y_B)=\tfrac12(ax_A-ax_B)=\tfrac{a}{2}(x_A-x_B)\\ y_N=\tfrac12(y_D+y_C)=\tfrac12(ax_D-ax_C)=\tfrac{a}{2}(x_D-x_C)\end{cases}$$

which, indeed, are equal, due to (2), ending the proof.

Comment: I'm impressed by this solution compared to mine; thank you for submitting it. I hadn't thought of using the angle bisector with Cartesian coordinates, but setting it as the x axis is a great simplification.

Answer (score 3):

We will use complex numbers.

Let the angle bisector divide the angle in two equal angles of $\theta$ degrees and intersect $\overline{DC}$ at point T. Therefore:

$\frac{t-e}{|t-e|} = e^{i\theta}\frac{d-e}{|d-e|}$
$\frac{c-e}{|c-e|} = e^{i\theta}\frac{t-e}{|t-e|}$
Multiplying those two yields:
$\frac{(t-e)^2}{|t-e|^2} = \frac{(d-e)(c-e)}{|d-e||c-e|} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{t-e}{\bar{t} -\bar{e}} = e^{i2\theta}$

Now:
WLOG: AD = BC =1
Therefore
$\frac{n-m}{\bar{n}-\bar{m}} = \frac{a+b-c-d}{\bar{a} + \bar{b} - \bar{c} - \bar{d}} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{n-m}{\bar{n}-\bar{m}} = \frac{e^{i2\theta}+1}{e^{-i2\theta}+1}$

$\overline{MN} \parallel \overline{ET}\Longleftrightarrow \frac{n-m}{\bar{n}-\bar{m}} = \frac{t-e}{\bar{t} -\bar{e}}$

WTS:
$\frac{n-m}{\bar{n}-\bar{m}} = \frac{t-e}{\bar{t} -\bar{e}}$
$\therefore \frac{e^{i2\theta}+1}{e^{-i2\theta}+1} = e^{i2\theta}$
$\therefore e^{i2\theta}+1 =(e^{-i2\theta}+1) e^{i2\theta}$
$\therefore e^{i2\theta}+1 = 1+ e^{i2\theta}$
Which is true hence the condition is established.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It is convenient to place the intersection point $ \ E \ $ of the extensions of sides $ \ AD \ $ and $ \ BC \ $ of the quadrilateral at the origin in the Argand plane and to arrange that  side $ \ AD \ $ of the quadrilateral be along the $ \ \mathfrak{Re}-$axis, with  $ \ A \ $ and $ \ D \ $ at distances $ \ r \ $ and $ \ s \ $ from the origin, respectively.  We take side $ \ BC \ $ to lie on a ray from the origin in the direction $ \ \theta \ \ , \ $ with the distance between $ \ B \ $ and $ \ C \ $ being the same as that between $ \ A \ $ and $ \ D \ $ but displaced along the ray by an amount $ \ \Delta \ $ relative to $ \ AD \ \ ; \ $ we then have $ \ B \ $ and $ \ C \ $ at $ \ (r + \Delta) \ cis \ \theta \ $ and $ \ (s + \Delta) \ cis \ \theta \ \ . \ $  (The diagram uses $ \ \Delta \ > \ 0 \ \ , \ $ but the sign of $ \ \Delta \ $ is immaterial to this argument.)

We now determine the position of the midpoint $ \ M \ $ of $ \ AB \ $ as
$$ \left[ \ \frac{r \ + \ (r + \Delta) · \cos \ \theta}{2} \ \right] \ + \ i·\left[ \ \frac{0 \ + \ (r + \Delta) \ \sin \ \theta}{2} \ \right] $$ $$ = \ \  \left[ \ \frac{r \ + \ (r + \Delta) · \cos \ \theta}{2} \ \right]  \ + \ i· \frac{ r + \Delta  }{2} · \sin \ \theta \ \ , $$
and similarly, midpoint $ \ N \ $ of $ \ CD \ $ is $ \ \left[ \ \frac{s \ + \ (s + \Delta) · \cos \ \theta}{2} \ \right]  \ + \ i· \frac{ s + \Delta  }{2} · \sin \ \theta \ \ . \ $  The angle $ \ \alpha \ $ that the segment $ \ \overline{MN} \ $ makes to the direction of the positive $ \ \mathfrak{Re}-$axis is thus given by
$$ \tan \alpha \ \ = \ \ \frac{\frac{ s + \Delta  }{2} · \sin \ \theta \ - \ \frac{ r + \Delta  }{2} · \sin \ \theta}{ \left[ \ \frac{s \ + \ (s + \Delta) · \cos \ \theta}{2} \ \right] \ - \ \left[ \ \frac{r \ + \ (r + \Delta) · \cos \ \theta}{2} \ \right] } \ \ = \ \ \frac{( s  \ - \ r) · \sin \ \theta }{ ( s  \ - \ r) \ + \ ( s  \ - \ r)· \cos \ \theta } $$
$$  = \ \ \frac{  \sin \ \theta }{ 1 \ + \  \cos \ \theta } \ \ = \ \ \tan \ \frac{\theta}{2} \ \ ,   $$
applying one form of the "tangent half-angle" formula.

In a sense, we are done:  we have shown that the slope of $ \overline{MN} \ $ is the same as that of the angle bisector of $ \ \angle CED \ \ , \ $ represented by $ \ \overline{EG} \ \ . \ $  While we're at it, though, we might look at the converse of the "angle bisector theorem" by marking the point $ \ G \ $ so as to satisfy the ratio $ \ \large{ \frac{EC}{ED}  =  \frac{CG}{DG} } \ \ . \ $  The length of the sides $ \ EC \ $ and $ \ ED \ $ of triangle $ \ \triangle ECD \ $ are the moduli of the numbers at $ \ C \ $ and $ \ D \ \ , \ $ so $ \ \frac{EC}{ED} = \frac{s \ + \ \Delta}{s} \ \ . \ $
If we parameterize the equation of the line on which $ \ DC \ $ lies as $$ \ \sigma \ = \ s \ + \ t·[ \ (s + \Delta) \ cis \ \theta \ - \ s \ ] \ \ , \ \ 0 \ \le \  t \ \le \  1 \ \ ,   $$
point $ \ G \ $ is located at $ \ t \ = \ \frac{s}{s + (s + \Delta)} \ = \ \frac{s}{2s +  \Delta} $ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ \sigma_G \ = \ s \ + \ \frac{s}{2s +  \Delta}·[ \ (s + \Delta) \ cis \ \theta \ - \ s \ ]  $$
$$ = \ \left[ \ \frac{s·(2s +  \Delta) \ - \ s·s}{2s +  \Delta} \ + \ \frac{s·(s +  \Delta)}{2s +  \Delta} · \cos \theta  \ \right] \ + \ i·\frac{s·(s +  \Delta)}{2s +  \Delta} · \sin \theta  $$
$$ = \ \left[ \ \frac{s^2 \ + \ s· \Delta}{2s +  \Delta} \ + \ \frac{s·(s +  \Delta)}{2s +  \Delta} · \cos \theta  \ \right] \ + \ i·\frac{s·(s +  \Delta)}{2s +  \Delta} · \sin \theta \ \ . $$

Hence, the angle $ \ \beta \ $ which the line $ \ EG \ $ makes to the direction of the positive $ \ \mathfrak{Re}-$axis is

$$ \tan \beta \ \ = \ \ \frac{\frac{s·(s +  \Delta)}{2s +  \Delta} · \sin \theta \ - \ 0}{ \left[ \ \frac{s·(s +  \Delta)}{2s +  \Delta} \ + \ \frac{s·(s +  \Delta)}{2s +  \Delta} · \cos \theta \ \right] \ - \ 0 } \ \ = \ \ \frac{s·(s +  \Delta) · \sin \ \theta }{ s·(s +  \Delta) \ + \ s·(s +  \Delta)· \cos \ \theta } $$
$$  = \ \ \frac{  \sin \ \theta }{ 1 \ + \  \cos \ \theta } \ \ = \ \ \tan \ \frac{\theta}{2} \ \ ,   $$
indicating that $ \ EG \ $ indeed bisects $ \ \angle CED \ \ . \ $  (An analogous argument can be made for $ \ EF \ \ . \ ) $

The application of complex numbers in the proofs of these propositions is marginal, since they can be managed with or without the use of trigonometry (as **Jean Marie** does).